# AVSpeechSynthsesizer on timer

Tags: ios, swift, avspeechsynthesizer

If a switch is turned on, text-to-word spoken every x seconds. The switch is on the first view controller, and the speech occurs after a segue to the second view controller.

**Code in the first view controller:**

```
@IBAction func speakwords(sender: AnyObject) {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("speaknotif", object: speakwords)
```

**Code in the second view controller:**

```
verride func viewDidLoad() {
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("talk:"), name: "speaknotif", object: self.view.window)


func talk(notification: NSNotification){guard let count = notification.object else {return}
        if Bool(TYPE_BOOL as! NSO) = "true"{

        let speechsynth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the code used to do this (setting a Bool and passing it to next vc)? And is there a way to call the func talk method every x amount of time?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, Notification Center was useless. Because you are calling post method before adding observer for that notification. So notification concept won't work there.

Instead of this, just set one **Bool** like "isSwitchSelected". And pass that value to next vc, check if the value is yes, then call **func talk** method.